# Test Angular service: pass value to variable in service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have this method in the service, my problem is that I want to replace the environment variables to run the code inside the if condition, but don't know how or if I'm using a wrong logic with this :(

```
      public async getPurchasableRewards() {
        let userStores: RewardStore[] = [];
        await this.sessionmApi.getUserRewardStores().then((r) => {      
          if (Array.isArray(r)) {
// Here I need to set a my value: environment.sessionmRewardStore
            if (environment.sessionmRewardStore) {
              userStores = r.filter((s) => {
                return s.id === environment.sessionmRewardStore;
              });
            } else {    
              userStores = r.filter((s) => {
//// Here I need to set a my value:environment.sessionmStoreEligibilityKeys 
                return s.eligibility_models.find((e) => environment.sessionmStoreEligibilityKeys.includes(e));
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

This is my test:

```
fit('should getPurchasableRewards return .....', (doneFn) => {
    const mock = {
      type: AppStateActions.PURCHASABLE_REWARDS,
      payload: MockIPurchasableReward
    };
 
    const spysgetValue = spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'getUserRewardStores').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(MockRewardStoreArray));

    //I want to send this variable to the service:
    environment.sessionmRewardStore='STORE-1'

    service.getPurchasableRewards().then((data) => {
      console.log('DATA PP:', data)
      doneFn();
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log('error', err)
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems fine, what error do you receive?

I would have a handle on the original and return it back to the original state though.

```
fit('should getPurchasableRewards return .....', (doneFn) => {
    const mock = {
      type: AppStateActions.PURCHASABLE_REWARDS,
      payload: MockIPurchasableReward
    };
 
    const spysgetValue = spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'getUserRewardStores').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(MockRewardStoreArray));
    // !! Get a handle on the original
    const originalSessionmRewardStore = environment.sessionmRewardStore;

    //I want to send this variable to the service:
    environment.sessionmRewardStore='STORE-1'

    service.getPurchasableRewards().then((data) => {
      console.log('DATA PP:', data)
      // !! Restore back to orignal
      environment.sessionmRewardStore = orignalSessionmRewardStore;
      doneFn();
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log('error', err)
    })
  })
```

Comment: The problem is that the value that I'm giving to the variable in the test file is not in the service so the if conditions are not working :(

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.